# Run jest tests using debug code lens with template string as test name

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, vscode-debugger

I have defined the following test:

```js
const INPUT = "hello world";

test(`Should work with ${INPUT} as input variable`, () => {
  expect(foo(INPUT)).notToThrow();
});
```

This runs when running all tests. However, when using vscode-jest code lens to only debug the specific test, it is skipped - the console output is: `Ran all test suites matching /testFoo.test.js/i with tests matching "Should work with \$\{INPUT\} as input variable".` Apparently the template string does not work in this case. How can I fix this and still use a template string for the test name?

Comment: hey @toivo Were you able to overcome this problem? If yes, how? :)

Comment: @arczi I haven't solved this specifically but now I am instead using each() function: `test.each([['Input A'], ['Input B']))('should work with %s as input variable', (input) => { expect(foo(input)).notToThrow(); });` which works with most recent alpha of vscode-jest